# Print File content including new line chracter in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I m using following code to read a file content.

```
@file_content = String.new
IO.foreach "/path/to/file" 
do |line|
   # Do something with line.
   @file_content << line
end
```

But If i m rendering @file_content in view, its not displaying new line chracter. Can anybody tell me how to capture new line chracter as well.

I have used this also.

```
@file_content = File.read("Path/to/file")
```

But its also not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML "newlines" are different from your regular newlines. Try inserting `<br/>` after each line of text

```
IO.foreach "/path/to/file" do |line|
   @file_content << line
   @file_content << '<br />'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
@file_content = String.new
read_file=File.open("Path/to/file").read
read_file.gsub!(/\n?/, "\n")
read_file.each_line do |line|
  print << line
end
```